# java.lang.NoSuchMethodErrorSetup on Hibernate cache with EhCache

Tags: hibernate, ehcache

I'm trying to add a cache to my project on Hibernate 5.2.4+ Spring 4.3.7, but getting an error when call `getCurrentSession().get(entityClass, id)` method:

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: `org.hibernate.cache.internal.DefaultCacheKeysFactory.staticCreateEntityKey(Ljava/lang/Object;Lorg/hibernate/persister/entity/EntityPersister;Lorg/hibernate/engine/spi/SessionFactoryImplementor;Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Object;`

Hibernate config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@PropertySource(value = {"classpath:hibernate.properties"})
public class HibernateConfig {
    private Environment environment;

    @Autowired
    HibernateConfig(Environment environment){
        this.environment = environment;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory(){
        LocalSessionFactoryBean localSessionFactoryBean = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        localSessionFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
        localSessionFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan("io.delivery.entity");
        localSessionFactoryBean.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());
        return localSessionFactoryBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource(){
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(environment.getProperty("hibernate.driverClass"));
        dataSource.setUrl(environment.getProperty("hibernate.url"));
        dataSource.setUsername(environment.getProperty("hibernate.username"));
        dataSource.setPassword(environment.getProperty("hibernate.password"));
        return dataSource;
    }

    private Properties hibernateProperties(){
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
        properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.show_sql"));
        properties.put("hibernate.format_sql", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.format_sql"));
        properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"));
        properties.put("show_sql", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.show_sql"));
        properties.put("hibernate.cache.region.factory_class", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.cache.region.factory_class"));
        return properties;
    }

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(SessionFactory sessionFactory){
        HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory);
        return transactionManager;
    }
```

hibernate.properties:

```
hibernate.cache.region.factory_class=org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory
```

pom.xml:

```
<!-- hibernate-jcache -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-jcache</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.10.Final</version>
</dependency>
<!-- hibernate-ehcache -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.10.Final</version>
</dependency>
<!-- ehcache -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
    <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
    <version>2.10.4</version>
</dependency>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you make sure you do not end up with conflicting hibernate dependencies on your classpath?

Comment: Most likely you are right, but I still can not understand exactly where the conflict.

Comment: You were right: I had version conflict with hibernate-core! Adding <hibernate.version>5.2.4.Final</hibernate.version> to properties in pom.xml and reference <version>${hibernate.version}</version> in all hibernate dependencies solved the problem. Thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had version conflict with hibernate-core! Adding 5.2.4.Final to properties in pom.xml and reference ${hibernate.version} in all hibernate dependencies solved the problem.

Comment: Yes. I should have added that, then, all your dependencies should be coherent.

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate 5.2 supports Ehcache in two ways. Ehcache 2 (which is what you are using) is natively supported by `hibernate-ehcache`. Ehcache 3 is supported through JCache.

Assuming you stay with Ehcache 2 (which match the region factory you have selected), you should remove `hibernate-jcache`.

Then, you need to make sure you have imported the Hibernate 5 version of `LocalSessionFactoryBean`.

I did that and it worked perfectly. My imports:

```
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;
```

My pom (jcache is still there but not needed):

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
  <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
  <version>1.4.195</version>
  <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
  <version>4.3.7.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
  <version>4.3.7.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
  <version>4.3.7.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
  <version>4.3.7.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<!-- hibernate-jcache -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-jcache</artifactId>
  <version>5.2.10.Final</version>
</dependency>
<!-- hibernate-ehcache -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
  <version>5.2.10.Final</version>
</dependency>
<!-- ehcache -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
  <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
  <version>2.10.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Yes, I have the same imports plus import javax.sql.DataSource;
import java.util.Properties;  I delete hibernate-jcache from pom.xml but still have an error.